# XML File and Payload

Tags: xml, mule

I have this XML file:

```
<phone>
<brand>LG</brand>
<price>10</price>
<screenSize>8</screenSize>
</phone>
```

[image: My Flow]

How to convert a received XML File via File Connector to use as #[payload] ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **File connector** **doesn't** convert the payload..
It simply pick up the payload from the file and send it into the flow.
What you need to do is to **extract** the element **values** from the XML to perform a Database access like **insert, update,selec**t etc.
To **extract** the elements value, you need to use **XPATH3** already mentioned by @JoostD​ in his answer
reference :- https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/xpath​

To extend @JoostD answer **more clearly** by a **simple example** as follows:-
Here you are **extracting** the value from the **XML** file and **inserting** into the **DB table** :-

```
  <file:connector name="File_Input" autoDelete="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
    <db:generic-config name="Generic_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Generic Database Configuration"/>
     <flow name="testxmlFlow1" > 
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\u450146\Downloads" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"  connector-ref="File_Input">
            <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="Test.xml" caseSensitive="false"/>
        </file:inbound-endpoint>  
        <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte-Array-to-String" />  
        <splitter expression="#[xpath3('/phone', payload, 'NODESET')]" doc:name="Splitter" />
        <logger message="brand :- #[xpath3('brand')]  price:- #[xpath3('price')] screenSize:-  #[xpath3('screenSize')]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
       <!-- Your Database code here -->
        <db:insert config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[INSERT INTO table1(brand,price,screenSize)VALUES (#[xpath3('brand')],#[xpath3('price')],#[xpath3('screenSize')])]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:insert>  
    </flow >​
```

Now as you can see, the payload has been picked by the File inbound from the file and then **converted** into String by the transformer, and then **Splitter** is used to split the value :-

```
 <splitter expression="#[xpath3('/phone', payload, 'NODESET')]" doc:name="Splitter" />
```

And now, you can directly insert your XML elements value using **XPATH3** into the DB with following SQL query :-

```
INSERT INTO table1(brand,price,screenSize)VALUES (#[xpath3('brand')],#[xpath3('price')],#[xpath3('screenSize')])​
```

Hope this help and you can perform other **SQL queries** with the **extracted** data as shown above :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the File to String transformer.

[https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/file-transport-reference#sts=File to String Transformer](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/file-transport-reference#sts=File%20to%20String%20Transformer)

After that you can use Xpath to get the values from your XML elements.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/xpath#sts=XPath

for example: #[xpath('/phone/brand')]